# Desynchronize animation between multiple models in useFrame() in react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

i am working on my Web Developer Portfolio in next.js, TypeScript and react-three-fiber.
In one page, I want to do a nice background who is inspired by this: https://codepen.io/algoregalore/pen/KJdBYP.

I want to make multiple models (in a .glb format) **appearing with a fade in animation in random positions in the canvas, wait for severals seconds then fade out slowly in order to reappear in another position and vice versa**.
The main thing is that each model will play its animation independently of the others, **out of sync**.

Here is the main code in TypeScript:

```
import {Suspense, useRef, useEffect, RefObject} from 'react';
import {Canvas, useFrame} from '@react-three/fiber';
import {Preload} from '@react-three/drei';
import {Group, Material, Mesh} from 'three';
import {SmartphoneModel, LaptopModel, CookieModel, PawnModel } from './models';
import {getNewPositionsArray, getRandomIntInclusive} from "@/utils/function";
import { ModelProps } from '@/constants/interface';

const componentModels = {
  smartphone: SmartphoneModel,
  laptop: LaptopModel,
  cookie: CookieModel,
  pawn: PawnModel
};

// this component is a wrapper to add new prop and control the animation of the model passed as prop
const ModelFadeWrapper = ({model, position, props} : {model : string, position? : [number, number, number], props : ModelProps}) => {
  const ref = useRef<Group>(null); // we create a ref to handle the model rotation
  const animationStarted = useRef<boolean>(false); // we create a ref that represent if the animation start
  const delayAnimationStart = getRandomIntInclusive(0,4) * 1000; // a random before the start of the animation
  console.log(delayAnimationStart);
  // we create a new var as a component model in order to pass new prop to it like position, ref and the other props.
  const SpecificModel = componentModels[model as keyof typeof componentModels];

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (ref.current?.children != null) {
      (ref.current.children as Mesh[]).forEach((mesh)=>{
        const material = mesh.material as Material;
        material.opacity = 0;
      });
      ref.current.visible = false;
      setTimeout(()=>{
        if (ref.current != null) {
          ref.current.visible = true;
          animationStarted.current = true;
          console.log(model);
        }
      },delayAnimationStart);
    }
  },[]);

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    if (ref.current?.children != null && animationStarted) {
      ref.current.rotation.y += 0.01; 
    }
  });

  return (
    <SpecificModel modelRef={ref} position={position} {...props}/>
  );
};


// this component represent the background canvas of the about page
const AboutBGCanvas = () => {
  let modelList:{name:string,key:string,props:ModelProps}[] = [
    {name:"pawn", key:"Pawn1",props:{scale:0.1}},
    {name:"pawn", key:"Pawn2", props:{scale:0.1}},
    {name:"laptop", key:"Laptop1",props:{ rotation:[0.8,0,0], scale:0.8}},
    {name:"laptop", key:"Laptop2",props:{ rotation:[0.8,0,0], scale:0.8}},
    {name:"smartphone", key:"Smartphone1",props:{ scale:0.005}},
    {name:"smartphone", key:"Smartphone2",props:{ scale:0.005}},
    {name:"cookie", key:"Cookie1",props:{ scale:1}}
  ]; // this array contain model component
  let positionModelList:[number,number,number][] = getNewPositionsArray(7,{x:[-3,3],y:[-3,3]},1.6); // this array represent all the positions of the respective models in the canvas
  modelList.forEach((modelObj,index)=>{ // for each model object of modelList we add the position value to the props object
    modelObj.props.position = positionModelList[index];
  });

  return (
    <div className='w-full h-auto absolute inset-0 z-[-1]'>
      <Canvas>
        <directionalLight position={[10, 10, 5]} intensity={2} />
        <directionalLight position={[-10, -10, -5]} intensity={1} />
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          {
            modelList.map((model, index)=>
              <ModelFadeWrapper key={model.key} model={model.name} position={positionModelList[index]} props={model.props}/>
            )
          }
        </Suspense>
        <Preload all/>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AboutBGCanvas;
```

I manage to display the .gbl models in the canvas and to access the rotation and material property of each mesh of the model. (so I can use the opacity).
I create a list of object in modelList that I will use later to create the models and I generate a list of spreaded vector positions (x,y,z) to set the positions of all models in the canvas.
Then inside the ModelFadeWrapper, I pass the ref and the props object (position, rotation) in the model and I modify the opacity and the rotation of the model by using the **ref**.
For the moment, I test by only changing the y rotation of all the models inside the **useFrame()**.

```
useFrame((state, delta) => {
    if (ref.current?.children != null && animationStarted) {
       ref.current.rotation.y += 0.01; 
    }
});
```

But all the models play theirs animations at the same time even though I set a setTimeout to desynchronise the start of the all model's animation.
The rotation is in sync with all the models.
What can I do to set the rotation for each model not play at the same time?
Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to achieve "frame-by-frame" animation, IMO for your use case it is rather complex to implement and maintain.

You could switch for "imperative animations" with a "Tween" engine (for example [gsap](https://gsap.com/)).
With such it is convenient to set individual [tweens](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Tween/) that you can organise into [timeline](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline?_highlight=timeline).

[Example here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/r3f-gsap-n2pj34).

Comment: I have check the documentation and sadly, I don't believe that it is possible for my use case.
while gsap is a very powerful tool to handle the position, rotation of dom element and even 3D object, it can't change the opacity of a 3DObject.
Since I have a Group of mesh for a model I need to set the material's opacity of each mesh children of the 3DObject to make it fade away.
And the timeline even with a refObject to the three group can't access to all of the opacity property of all the materials...
Maybe I need to see with the Three.clock to create the desync

Comment: At the end, it turn out it work pretty well with an hack, I just used a fog behind the models and played with their z axis with gsap to make them fade in/out.